# How to turn a number to zero if the result of a calculation is negative inside a squareroot in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a query that can result in a negative squareroot, leading to an error. I'm using BigQuery.
Is there a way to turn the result in to a 0 if inside de POWER() function is less than 0?

Here's my query:

```
UPDATE `table` SET 
SW_FERTL = CASE
WHEN POR_CLEAN < 0.04 THEN 1
WHEN (1/((rho_matrix-RHOB)/(rho_matrix-rho_mud_filt)))*POWER(((RW/ILD)+(POWER((0.3*VSHALE/2), 2)-(0.3*VSHALE/2))), 0.5) > 1 THEN 1
ELSE (1/((rho_matrix-RHOB)/(rho_matrix-rho_mud_filt)))*POWER(((RW/ILD)+(POWER((0.3*VSHALE/2), 2)-(0.3*VSHALE/2))), 0.5)
END
WHERE DEPTH_M IS NOT NULL
```

The negative squareroot can happen here:

```
POWER(((RW/ILD)+(POWER((0.3*VSHALE/2), 2)-(0.3*VSHALE/2))), 0.5)
```

So, if the result of

```
((RW/ILD)+(POWER((0.3*VSHALE/2), 2)-(0.3*VSHALE/2)))
```

is less than zero, I would like to set it to zero instead.

Is it possible to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `GREATEST()`:

```
GREATEST(0, ((RW/ILD)+(POWER((0.3*VSHALE/2), 2)-(0.3*VSHALE/2))))
```

Answer (score 0):

In many (if not most) practical cases you want to distinguish zeros coming from `power(-4, .5)` vs. `power(0, .5)`

So, you can consider below approach

```
SAFE.POWER(((RW/ILD)+(POWER((0.3*VSHALE/2), 2)-(0.3*VSHALE/2))), 0.5)
```

above returns `NULL` in case of negative argument

Comment: Thanks for your reply, will use in the future. But in this specific case I need it to show as zero.